# float or double precision

Tags: sql, postgresql, floating-point, precision

When I tell postgreSQL to show a column as `float`, I always get as a result "`double precision`".

Is it the same?

Comment: Did you consider checking the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html): "`float` with no precision specified is taken to mean `double precision`."?

Answer (score 6):

Like Damien quoted from [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT):

> PostgreSQL also supports the SQL-standard notations `float` and `float(p)` for specifying inexact numeric types.
>   Here, `p` specifies the minimum acceptable precision in **binary** digits.
>   PostgreSQL accepts `float(1)` to `float(24)` as selecting the `real` type,
>   while `float(25)` to `float(53)` select `double precision`.
>   Values of `p` outside the allowed range draw an error.
>   `float` with no precision specified is taken to mean `double precision`.

PostgreSQL, like other databases, supports the SQL standard by supplying an appropriate data type when a certain SQL standard type is requested. Since `real` or `double precision` fit the bill here, they are taken instead of creating new redundant types.

The disadvantage is that the data type of a column may read different from what you requested, but as long as it handles your data the way it should, is that a problem?